# Form submited by jQuery does not insert on DDBB

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, insert

I have  a simple form that I am trying to submit by jQuery. This is it:

```
        <form id="turn_conf" action='turn_insert.php' method="POST">
                    <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="tu_name" name="tu_name">         
                    <input type="submit" class="botonEnvio" value="Crear">
        </form>
```

And a jQuery function that by the moment does not seem to work, neither the "It seems I'm working" alert is displayed on screen

```
    $('#turn_conf').on('submit', validaDatos)

function validaDatos(e) {
    var nombreTurno = $('input[name=tu_name]').val();

    $.post({url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data: { tu_name:nombreTurno },
            success:feedback })
    e.preventDefault(); }

function feedback (datos) {
    alert("Seems I'm working!")}
```

No value is being inserted on DDBB. Here you have what is on the insert PHP file "turn_insert.php":

```
$nombreTurno = $_POST['tu_name'];

$insertar = mysql_query("INSERT INTO turn_conf (tu_id,tu_name,tu_status) VALUES ('','$nombreTurno','1')");
```

Console shows error: error on console: POST localhost/Gestion/%5Bobject%20Object%5D 404 Not Found

Any suggestion about what is going wrong here? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: Hi @hemanth. No, neither when loading or submiting the form. Thank you.

Comment: Excuse me @hemanth, YES, I do have this error on console: POST http://localhost/Gestion/%5Bobject%20Object%5D 404 Not Found - Excuse me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the `success` argument is being passed the result of `feedback` because you are calling it rather than passing the reference to the function. Also you are using the `$.ajax` version by passing an object to the method. `$.post` breaks the object down into parameters. Change to:

```
$.post($(this).attr('action'), { tu_name:nombreTurno }).success(feedback);
```

Second **never** pass user input straight into your SQL queries. You are open to SQL injection and all kinds of nastiness. Use bound parameters: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Comment: Ok. After changing feedback calling, no alert is displayed on screen what I think is right, as in deed the function is not successful. About bound parameters, this is a Beta version of a ERP, so first basic things must work, as inserts. On a near phase I'll have these bound parameters in mind. Thank you vey much.

Answer (score 1):

Use F12 in Chrome to check if data was submitted to specified URL. Use Console.log(); for debugging JavaScript. Alert was an debugging option many years ago.

Comment: Thank you @Alexander. I've done and Chrome has shown this: ERROR
POST http://localhost/Gestion/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found)

Comment: I'll invest if this is what makes my form not submiting onto the DB